# How to show full size

Tags: ios, view, autolayout

I create cell with autolayout.

```
    NSDictionary* subviewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView,_labelName,_labelDate,_labelActivityText);

    NSString* stringConstraints = @"|-8-[_imageView(==50)]-17-[_labelName]-5-[_labelDate]-14-|";
    NSArray* arrayConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:stringConstraints
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:subviewDictionary];
    [self addConstraints:arrayConstraints];
```

It works, but need to display _labeldate full size, width _labeldate varies from 30 to 60.

P.S. Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to increase the date label's resistance to compression. By default, a label has a compression resistance priority of 750. You only need to increase this priority by 1 for the date label. This will cause the name label's content to compress instead.

```
[_labelDate setContentCompressionResistancePriority:751 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Comment: **bilobatum**,thanks, this work. But it is possible to register in stringConstraints??

Comment: @user2828120 I don't think it's possible.